# Your request has been throttled by EC2, please make sure you have enough API rate limit

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am deploying my lambdas in VPC from the cloudformation template .yml file and when I upload the template it gave me the error that.

```js
Resource handler returned message: "Your request has been throttled by EC2, please make sure you have enough API rate limit. EC2 Error Code: RequestLimitExceeded. EC2 Error Message: Request limit exceeded. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: dee74a29-9148-40a0-970e-9afc1d2fba76, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 06c6d3aa-4a0d-1f31-4899-bbcc6d0d869f, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

But when I try to deploy without VPC it works fine and created a stack successfully

Comment: Are you deploying many VPC lambdas at the same time?

Comment: We are running into this also when trying to update our lambdas from one VPC to another